# iOS Tabbar - Change to first tab and first ViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I need some help regarding my Tabbar application.

Currently my Tabbar looks like the following:

- TabbarController

  - Tab1

    - NavigationController

      - ViewController1
      - ViewController2
  - Tab2

    - ViewController3

Assume ViewController2 is the current displayed ViewController. Now I switch to ViewController3 and want to switch to ViewController1 programmatically.

The problem is, since the active ViewController in Tab1 is ViewController2

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
```

will always switch to ViewController2.
But how can I switch to ViewController1 in that case?

This also doesn't work out for me:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController
= [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Would be glad fro some hints.

Answer (score 3):

You have to pop viewController2 from your navigation controller. Just do

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
[(UINavigationController*)[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Answer (score 3):

After setting the `selectedIndex` in code, you can then pop back to the root view controller of the navigation stack:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
UINavigationController *navController = self.tabBarController.selectedViewController;
[navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use something like

```
UINavigationController *navController=(UINavigationController*)[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 version

```
 self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
 let navController = self.tabBarController?.selectedViewController as! UINavigationController
 navController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```